# Twilio Programmable Chat - TwilioChatClient crashing on iOS due to memory exception

Tags: ios, swift, twilio

Has anyone ever run into an issue before where `TwilioChatClient` on iOS crashes during initialization for certain accounts? Using v[1.0.2](https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/chat/changelogs/ios#programmable-chat-ios-102-june-2-2017) of the SDK.

In an iOS app, I am getting a JWT registration token from my backend server as described in the [Twilio Chat REST API docs](https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/rest/access-tokens). With that token, I am attempting to initialize a `TwilioChatClient`:

```
TwilioChatClient.chatClient(withToken: token, properties: props, delegate: self) { (result, chatClient) -> Void in
// <snip>
```

This approach works for most accounts, but for one account I am debugging, the app crashes after ~30-60 seconds and the callback is never called.

This "requesting sync list token" and "got sync list token" happens repeatedly until the app crashes. It looks like an infinite loop. The timestamps are super close together, and the channel SID never changes:

```
2017-06-07 11:28:15.747551-0700 [2030:844877] IPM[3]: 0x16e5eb000 | 06/07/11:28:15.747 | INFO  | IPM | channels: got sync list token: /CHxxxyyyzzz/ size: 250
2017-06-07 11:28:15.748060-0700 [2030:844877] IPM[4]: 0x16e5eb000 | 06/07/11:28:15.747 | DEBUG | IPM | requesting sync list CHxxxyyyzzz
2017-06-07 11:28:15.748262-0700 [2030:844877] IPM[3]: 0x16e5eb000 | 06/07/11:28:15.748 | INFO  | IPM | channels: got sync list token: /CHxxxyyyzzz/ size: 250
2017-06-07 11:28:15.748759-0700 [2030:844877] IPM[4]: 0x16e5eb000 | 06/07/11:28:15.748 | DEBUG | IPM | requesting sync list CHxxxyyyzzz
2017-06-07 11:28:15.748894-0700 [2030:844877] IPM[3]: 0x16e5eb000 | 06/07/11:28:15.748 | INFO  | IPM | channels: got sync list token: /CHxxxyyyzzz/ size: 250
2017-06-07 11:28:15.749438-0700 [2030:844877] IPM[4]: 0x16e5eb000 | 06/07/11:28:15.749 | DEBUG | IPM | requesting sync list CHxxxyyyzzz
2017-06-07 11:28:15.749656-0700 [2030:844877] IPM[3]: 0x16e5eb000 | 06/07/11:28:15.749 | INFO  | IPM | channels: got sync list token: /CHxxxyyyzzz/ size: 250
```

The previous snippets repeat for ~30 more seconds, then the app crashes:

```
Message from debugger: Terminated due to memory issue
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I work on the [Twilio Chat](https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/chat) product.

That is an issue that we discovered in the 1.0.2 release. Please [update to the latest version 1.0.3](https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/chat/sdks#ios-sdk) which [includes a fix](https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/chat/changelogs/ios#programmable-chat-ios-103-june-8-2017).